# Scala - play json trait serialisation

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

In scala, I have the following trait and classes defined (names used only for illustrative purposes):

```
trait Entity {
  def x() : Collection
}

case class X(x : Int, y : Int) extends Entity {
  def x() : Collection = XCollection()
}

case class Y(x : Int, y : Int) extends Entity {
  def x() : Collection = YCollection()
}
```

While the class instances are created by parsing the response from a web service REST API.

Although the approach using the play-json library works in the case parsing the response, and returning a class representation of the response, I've been struggling with the following: having a generic function taking a type parameter, whereas T : Entity, and returning an instance of type T.

For example, consider the following:

```
def parse[T <: Entity](json : String) : Option[T] = Json.parse(json).asOpt[T](Variants.format[T])
```

Given a type T, I would like to parse the JSON string and produce an instance of type T, whereas the instance is a derivation of the trait Entity. However, I keep getting a compile error in regard to the reflection API:

```
Error:(25, 96) exception during macro expansion: 
scala.ScalaReflectionException: type T is not a class
at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asClass(Symbols.scala:323)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asClass(Symbols.scala:73)
at julienrf.variants.Variants$Impl$.baseAndVariants(Variants.scala:132)
at julienrf.variants.Variants$Impl$.formatDiscriminator(Variants.scala:99)
at julienrf.variants.Variants$Impl$.format(Variants.scala:94)
def parse[T <: Entity](json : String) : Option[T] =     Json.parse(json).asOpt[T](Variants.format[T])
                                                                                           ^
```

Therefore, I would appreciate for some help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better allow implicits solve your format requirements, than using some kind of factory:

```
def parse[T <: Entity](json: String)(implicit r: Reads[T]): Option[T] = 
     Json.parse(json).asOpt[T]
```

Then if you have a format in current context implicitly defined, `parse` will work:

```
implicit val XFormat = Json.format[X]

parse[X](Json.stringify(Json.toJson(X(1, 2))) // returns X(1, 2)
```

**Update**

You can make it as a factory, if you really want it. I would question whether it's worth doing that, but in theory I could imagine some distinct situations where you would not want to use implicit mechanics. Still I think if implicits does not work for you, you might have an architecture problem in your code

```
  import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Reads}

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  trait Entity
  case class X(x : Int, y : Int) extends Entity
  case class Y(x : Int, y : Int) extends Entity


  val mapping = Map[Type, Reads[_]](typeOf[X] -> Json.format[X], typeOf[Y] -> Json.format[Y])
  def getFormat[T](tpe: Type): Reads[T] =
    mapping(tpe).asInstanceOf[Reads[T]]

  def parse[T : TypeTag](json: String): Option[T] = {
    val map = mapping(implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe)
    Json.parse(json).asOpt[T](getFormat(implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe))
  }

  println(parse[X]("""{"x": 5, "y": 6}"""))
  println(parse[Y]("""{"x": 5, "y": 6}"""))
```

Comment: Although the problem is valid, there is still another point left: every time you need to parse an instance of type Entity, i.e. either X or Y instances, you need to explicitly provide the format or reads, which is exactly the thing I've been trying to avoid. Rather, I am seeking for the following: parse[X](jsonString), whereas the serialiser should be determined in the parse function.

Comment: @dsafa And please note that you don't need explicitly provide the format. In the first example the format is supplied implicitly, that's why the keyword is there

Comment: The above solution using reflection for the sake of acquiring the type tag and mapping the format to the type tag works perfectly! Thanks a lot!